# Lost coins of the Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, cpp-ethereum, balances

Please help me to understand the situation:

I sent coins using an Ethereum transaction

0x0ae4b10100ddd1da0a22e6130903294dad57aa763a0a74580660904edc4512b2

Coins from the balance were written off but the address was not received, the transaction in the blockade by (0x0ae4b10100ddd1da0a22e6130903294dad57aa763a0a74580660904edc4512b2) does not appear!

Can coins disappear? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There was the Ethereum network hick-up due to extra-high load during the Status ICO crowdfunding. The transactions are delayed for up to 24h. For example, my transaction was completed 18h after the funds were withdrawn from the Coinbase account. So, just wait a bit - and you will get your funds.

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0ae4b10100ddd1da0a22e6130903294dad57aa763a0a74580660904edc4512b2) you can see that no transaction with the hash you have posted has been mined to the blockchain.

This could be for a number of reasons.

If the transaction has not been mined, you will not have lost any Ether.